# How do I check if monerod is up to date

Tags: full-node

Is there a way to tell if a node I am running is "current" along with the rest of the network?  For example, if I am checking transactions against my node, how do I first ensure that my node's copy of the blockchain is the most current and up to date?

Reason being- I'd like to be able to write a script that checks for this and alerts me if my node is running behind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways you can do that:

- check your node is at most one or two blocks behind the highest height known in its peers
- check whether a new release is available

The first one can by done by running `sync_info` in monerod, which reports your height as well as that of your peers. The RPC to get that information is `sync_info`.

The second one can be done by running "update check" in monerod. The RPC to do this is `update`.

Comment: `monerod sync_info | grep Height` seems to work nice